# How do i display an image front-end using rest call?

Tags: java, jquery, spring

I have a rest controller which is written in **spring 4.1** , please refer below code

```
 @RequestMapping(value = "/image", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    public ResponseEntity<InputStreamResource> downloadUserAvatarImage() {
        GridFSDBFile gridFsFile = App.getImageResponse();

        return ResponseEntity.ok()
                .contentLength(gridFsFile.getLength())
                .contentType(MediaType.parseMediaType(gridFsFile.getContentType()))
                .body(new InputStreamResource(gridFsFile.getInputStream()));
    }
```

now my problem is i have html block when i load the page 
http://host.com/title
title page html is posted below

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Host.com some title</h1>
        <p>Some content</p>
        <div id='loadImage'></div>
        ...
        some content
        ...
    </body>
</html>
```

i want to load the image  in that div mentioned by an id `loadImage` by calling my rest controller say `http://www.host.com/getMyImage`

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why JQuery in First place ??

Since your response is returning the image you can directly give the url 
`http://www.host.com/getMyImage`

```
 <html>
        <body>
            <h1>Host.com some title</h1>
            <p>Some content</p>
            <div id='loadImage'>
               <img src="http://www.host.com/getMyImage">
            </div>
            ...
            some content
            ...
        </body>
    </html>
```